# Question on the implementation of Else If

Tags: java, .net, c, language-agnostic, if-statement

I've wondered about the implementation of else if before, specifically why two keywords are needed, and why the keywords aren't joined. In python though, elif is used as the else if control flow statement. I was wondering how a general compiler would interpret else if.

Does a compiler treat else if as a single token? Or is else if simply an else with implicit block scope that transfers through to the if underneath?

Single Token:

```
if (some_condition) {
    some_statement();
}
else_if (some_other_condition) {
    other_statement();
}
else {
    default_statement();
}
```

Or Else then If:

```
if (some_condition) {
    some_statement();
}
else { // compiler generated block scope 
    if (some_other_condition) {
         other_statement();
    }
    else {
        default_statement();
    }
```

}

I'm aware that different languages and compilers could implement this differently, but if anyone has specific details about a particular language (or compiler) I'd be interested to hear them.

Comment: Some languages use a 'single token' `else if` in the form of `elif` or `elsif` or similar. The *tokenizer should not be aware* of the grammar -- e.g. it just spits out a series of tokens and has no way of any "higher" constructs (doing so results in languages like Perl ... try to parse that :p)

Comment: In PHP you have both. You can write `elseif` or `else if`, and they will be interpreted as you pointed out. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: @MartinodF: Yes, PHP and its retarded "dual syntax"...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - I can only agree with that ;)

Comment: Two keywords needed? We _already_ need `if` and `else`. `elseif` is the redundant keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C, at least, `else if` is not a separate language construct.  As you guessed, it's no different from `if (x) { ... } else { if (y) { ... } }`.

In certain languages (and presumably Python is one of them), then syntax/whitespace rules wouldn't allow the parser to interpret `else if` correctly, hence the `elif` (or equivalent) construct.

Comment: Same deal with Perl, where omitting the braces after an if clause is not optional.  Therefore the `elsif` token was created.

Comment: there is no such thing as "else if" in C or Java. Its purely artificial. It is even dangerous/expensive from code maintainability perspective. For example, in case someone wants to insert extra code or log statement into else clause, e.g. before it was "else if", but they added "else printf(log); if ..." would completely break existing logic...hard to spot! However when using braces it is not the case.

Answer (score 5):

In C, the grammar of an `if` statement is simply:

```
if (expression) statement [else statement]
```

A *statement* can be a *block-statement*, which looks like:

```
{ statement-list }
```

but it doesn't have to be.  So in the "else if" case, it is just an `else` keyword which is followed by a single statement, and that statement happens to be an `if` statement.

Conceptually, it's the same as this:

```
if (x == 0) {
    return;
} else while (x > 0) {
    foo(x--);
}
```

"else if" isn't handled any differently to "else while", or any other similar construct.

Comment: +1 for talking about grammars. Easily the best answer here. It's all about how the grammar specifies the language.

Answer (score 3):

In C, `else if` is two keywords and the following are effectively the same:

```
if (a) 
{
}
else if (b) 
{
}
```

and

```
if (a) 
{
}
else 
{
    if (b) 
    {
    }
}
```

"else if" isn't special, at least not in C.

Comment: I would say that artificial construct "else if" is even dangerous/expensive from code maintainability perspective. In case someone wants to insert extra code or log statement in to else, e.g. before it was "else if", but they added "else printf(log); if ..." would completely break existing logic. However when using braces it is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that there's an implied pair of paranthesis surrounding the if statement.

Much how you can write

```
if(x==1)
   System.Console.WriteLine("1");
else
   System.Console.WriteLine("2");
```

instead of

```
if(x==1)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("1");
}
else
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

The else if (cond) {action} notation is, as you described, is shorthand for else { if (cond) {action}}

The paranthesis are omitted for readability.

```
if(x==1)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("1");
}
else
{
   if (x==2)
   {
       System.Console.WriteLine("2");
   }
}
```

Is harder to follow than

```
if(x==1)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("1");
}
else if(x==2)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The C# language spec (4.0) section 8.7.1 shows that the grammar for the `if` statement is just:

`if (boolean-expression) embedded-statement else embedded-statement`

So it parses the `else if` as an `else` followed by an `if` statement.  This behavior is emulating the behavior of C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to treat `else if` as a single token, because treating `else` and `if` as two separate tokens with separate functionality still works.

For example:

```
if (a) {
    ...
} else if (b) {
    ....
} else {
    .....
}
```

Is semantically equivalent to:

```
if (a) {
    ...
} else {
    if (b) {
        ....
    } else {
        .....
    }
}
```

And most compilers for C-style languages will generate the exact same parse tree for both examples, because they are equivalent in the grammar of the language.